# Laravel Eloquent Joins

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have below query in core php:

```
SELECT DISTINCT device_tocken FROM push_details JOIN users ON users.id=push_details.user_id
```

I have to integrate it in laravel 4

Application already have `User extends Eloquent` class

I created Push_details class as below

```
class Push_details extends Eloquent {

public $table = 'push_details';

public function User() {
    return $this->hasMany('\User','id');
}
```

}

```
    Table : users
        Primary key : id

    Table: push_details
        Primary key: id
        Foreign key: user_id belongsTo('users.id');
```

But i m not able to get expected result.

One more thing i didn't write anything in User's model yet.

Comment: Have you written any query? Please post if you have.

Comment: @Ravi Added an answer

Comment: @Ravi And it worked??? The problem is in the model not the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to join table is.. to join it, as Eloquent relations don't work using joins but separate queries with `WHERE IN` clauses. So this will do:

```
DB::table('push_details')
   ->select('device_tocken')
   ->distinct()
   ->join('users','users.id','=','push_details.user_id')
   ->get();
```

Above will return `array` of `stdObject's` so or if you need Eloquent `Collection` with `Eloquent` models as a result replace `DB::table('push_details')->select...` with `PushDetails::select...`

Now, correct your relations, as they are wrong:

```
// PushDetails model (as previously stated, I suggest renaming it to StudlyCase)
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\User','user_id'); // user_id is may be omitted here
}

// User model
public function pushDetails() {
    return $this->hasMany('\PushDetails','user_id'); // user_id is may be omitted here as well
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `User` model, you need to link back to the `PushDetails` model, like so

   ```
   class User extends Eloquent {
       public function push_details() {
           return $this->belongsTo('PushDetails');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use CamelCase for Class names, because laravel has several functions, in which CamelCase are changed to snake_case
3. Change

   ```
   public function User() {
       return $this->hasMany('\User','id');
   }
   ```

to

```
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
```

See the docs '[Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)' for more...